# .htaccess url rewrite GET parameter and remove .php without breaking javascript/css

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Sorry if I explain my problem badly, It's a little hard to explain what's going wrong***
I've been playing around with the `.htaccess` file for a while now, Trying to get this to work.
I have the following files in my website directory:

```
- index.php
- generator.php
- menu.php
- gift-history.php
- stats.php

- images/
    - bg-stars.png
    - avatar.png

- css/
    - style.css
    - glow.css
    - background.css

- js/
    - script.js
    - jquery.js
    - destiny.js
    - snowflake.js
```

The three folders are `images,css and js`.
The generator.php requires a `$_GET` paremeter to know what generator to load.
So far, i've been using the following url:
`http://tryhardhusky.com/generator.php?t=destiny`
For the other pages, I have the following code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value display_errors Off
php_flag magic_quotes 1
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 1
php_value mbstring.http_input auto
php_value date.timezone America/New_York
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This pretty much removes the `.php` extension from the file name, So files that would be:
`http://tryhardhusky.com/gift-history.php`
becomes:
`http://tryhardhusky.com/gift-history`

I'm trying to get the following page:
`http://tryhardhusky.com/generator.php?t=destiny`
to rewrite as
`http://tryhardhusky.com/generator/destiny`

All my previous attempts have broken the js and css, Returning a 404 error when loading the page (despite the location being correct)
[Error 404 Not Found: http://tryhardhusky.com/js/jquery.js ]

Any clue how I can do this without breaking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your current code by this one in your htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# rewrite /generator.php?t=XXX to /generator/XXX
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/generator\.php\?t=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ generator/%1? [R=301,L]

# hide PHP extension for existing files
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+?)\.php(?:\s|\?) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite /generator/XXX to /generator.php?t=XXX
RewriteRule ^generator/([^/]+)$ generator.php?t=$1 [L]

# internally rewrite to PHP file extension (if existing)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: That rewrites the url the way I want it, But Now I'm getting a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` error when trying to load tryhardhusky.com/js/jquery.js

Comment: For which url do you have this error ? Which target file ? That certainly comes from relative paths (you should use absolute paths)

Comment: If you view the developers console on `http://tryhardhusky.com/generator/destiny`, You can see the 500 error despite the js file being fine.

Comment: Line 68 of destiny.js: should be `'url': "/gen.json.php",` instead of `'url': "gen.json.php",`. You now need to use *absolute paths* **everywhere** (in your js files for ajax calls, in your html files for ressources as images, js, css, href links and in your php files for includes)

Comment: hey, I just updated the code to "/gen.json.php" but it's still giving me the same error :(

Comment: Problem is coming from `http://tryhardhusky.com/gen.json.php` (which redirects to `http://tryhardhusky.com/gen.json`). What do you have in this file ?

Comment: I had a php error in the gen.json (it was in a "generator" directory, I forgot to replace `require("../file.php")` with `require("file.php")`. It's all working now, Thanks so much Justin!